# Flutter-markdown: Writing an inline sytax/builder for colored text

Tags: flutter, syntax, colors, markdown, builder

I'm looking to implement dynamic text color with flutter-markdown using a custom syntax and parser. While the implementation below does successfully color text, I lose inner-text styling.

For example, the string

```html
"not blue <span data-color='rgb(0,0,255)'>**blue text**</span> not blue"
```

shows up as

[image]

rather than showing up blue and bold.

While dynamic color isn't really the purpose of markdown, it would make my project considerably easier (I would use flutter-html, but the limits on selectable text make me hesitant)

My current implementation is as follows:

```dart
class FontColorSyntax extends md.InlineSyntax {

//Hideous => matches groups as follows: <span data-color="rgb(1,2,3)">4</span>
  FontColorSyntax()

      : super(
            r'''<span(?:.*?)data-color=['"]rgb *\((?: *([0-9]{1,3}))[, ]+(?: *([0-9]{1,3}))[, ]+(?: *([0-9]{1,3}))[, ]*\)['"](?:.*?)>(.*?)</span>''');

  @override
  bool onMatch(md.InlineParser parse, Match match) {
    md.Element colorTag = md.Element.text('fontcolor', match.group(4) ?? "matched text");

    colorTag.attributes["fontColorRed"] = match.group(1) ?? "0";
    colorTag.attributes["fontColorGreen"] = match.group(2) ?? "0";
    colorTag.attributes["fontColorBlue"] = match.group(3) ?? "0";

    parse.addNode(colorTag);
    return true;
  }
}

class FontColorBuilder extends MarkdownElementBuilder {

  int getColor(md.Element el, String color) =>
      int.tryParse(el.attributes["fontColor$color"] ?? "0") ?? 0;

  @override
  Widget visitElementAfter(element, style) {

    final red = getColor(element, "Red");
    final green = getColor(element, "Green");
    final blue = getColor(element, "Blue");

    return SelectableText.rich(
      TextSpan(
          text: element.textContent,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, 1),
          )),
    );
  }
```

I'm still quite new to flutter/dart, so please forgive (but feel free to point out) any oddities in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a SelectableText returning another MarkdownBody widget should do the trick:

```
return MarkdownBody(
    styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet.fromTheme(ThemeData(
        textTheme:
            const TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, 1)
            )))),
    data: element.textContent);
```